# I want to put a td tag of full width inside a bootstrap table of different td tags

Tags: css, html-table, responsive

I am using a simple bootstrap table with almost 11 table cells (td), after the first table row (tr) I want to show a message when someone clicks on the first table row.
so to show that message I need one long table cell with the full width of the table... but unable to create the td.
Here is my simple table body

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Show full width message here</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Check out the [colspan attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="6">Show full width message here</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say that a `<td>` is of "full width", it should be mentioned in terms of columns which the `<td>` is going to be stretched over.

In `HTML` this term is denoted by the attribute [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan). Its value is arbitrary integer **without** any unit.

And as obvious, when you want a "full width" `<td>` this value will vary based on the total number of columns in that `<table>`.

So in your case based on the number of columns you should assign a value of 6 to the `colspan` attribute of that td. As shown below.

```
.....
<tr>
 <td colspan="6">Show full width message here</td>
</tr>
.....
```